# Disabling the submit button when there is no input/data

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Currently the submit button is active and shows an error message when its clicked with no data, but I want to change this so that the submit button is disabled until there is data.

```
               <Button
                onClick={submitId}
                loading={isLoading}
                type="submit"
                disabled={}
              >
                Submit
              </Button>
```

```
const submitId = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const result = await executeId(a, b);
    if (result) {
      available.custom.push(`${Name}.model`);
      setServiceResult(`${Name} created`);
    } else {
      setServiceResult("failed");
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
```

```
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Validate the data and pass the result to `disabled` prop

```
<Button
  onClick={submitId}
  loading={isLoading}
  type="submit"
  disabled={!a && !b}
>
  Submit
</Button>
```

Answer (score -1):

The other answer is correct. You need to check in your `disabled` attribute to whether your value is valid.

If you are using a `<form>` might want to add `required` to the input field.

Doing that will block submissions until the field has a value ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required)).

Comment: Since the submission is done using a `click` event on the button, using `required` won't block it.